# Passing Class and Method as parameter

Tags: java

I am looking out for a way to pass a `Class` and a `Method` both as parameters to a method. I have repetitive piece of code which I want to reduce.

I  want something like this:

```
public static void methodName(Class C, Method m ) {         
  C.m.sendKeys("item");                    
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use method references passed as a lambda;

```
methodName(C::m);
```

You need to specify the type (arguments and return value) of the function and use one of the existing functional interfaces or define your own.

If for example your function returns a boolean and takes an object of class T as input, you can use the predefined functional interface `Predicate`:

```
public static void methodName(Item item, Predicate<Item> p) {
    p.test(item);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not in java 8, you can pass interfaces with anonymous implementation in earlyer versions too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use `Consumer<...>` for this. For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void methodToPass(String arg) {...}
}

public static void methodName(Consumer<String> cons) {
    cons.accept("item");
}
```

Then call like:

```
methodName(MyClass::methodToPass);
```

---

This also works for instance methods, with the syntax:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
methodName(mc::methodToPass);
```

Or, using a `BiConsumer<...>`, in which case the first argument passed would have to be an instance on which to invoke the method:

```
methodName(MyClass::methodToPass);
```

```
public static void methodName(BiConsumer<MyClass, String> cons) {
    MyClass mc = ...;
    cons.accept(mc, "item");
}
```

---

This works as long as the method you're calling takes one argument of the type you specify as a type parameter for `Consumer<...>`.

There are other interfaces available like `Consumer<...>` that take work for different types of methods, in the [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package.